# Vee validate get previous value after vue set

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, vee-validate

I want to update v-model value by code and validate that field. So I am using **vue.set** method for updating value and then call **$validator.validate**. 
my code is something like that.

```
Vue.set(model,property, value);
vm.$validator.validate(property).then(function (valid) {
            if (!valid) {
                vm.$validator.flag(property, {
                    touched: true,
                    dirty: true
                });
            } 
        });
```

my validation rules code is somethng like that:

```
Validator.extend("val_compulsory", {
getMessage(field, args) {
    return args[0];
},
validate(value) {
    return {
        valid: !!value,
        data: {
            required: true
        }
    };
}
}, { computesRequired: true });
```

but in val_compulsory validator I always get previous value which is before **vue.set**. Is there any way to get latest value in vee-validator validation methods after vue.set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Vue.set(model,property, value);
vm.$nextTick(function() {
    vm.$validator.validate(property).then(function (valid) {
        if (!valid) {
            vm.$validator.flag(property, {
                touched: true,
                dirty: true
            });
        } 
    });
});
```